# Cannot extend generic interface in Groovy

Tags: oop, generics, inheritance, grails, groovy

I am trying to implement a spring interface called the ObjectPostProcessor interface in groovy to create a new class.
I have tried to do it using a new class implementing the interface and also by creating a new anonymous class. I keep seeing an error saying.

**Groovyc: Can't have an abstract method in a non-abstract class.**

Which makes me think that groovy doesn't consider the abstract method of the class as overriden correctly.

Below is the code example that is breaking.

What is the correct way to implement this kind of an interface in groovy ?

```
interface ObjectPostProcessor<T> {

    /**
     * Initialize the object possibly returning a modified instance that should be used
     * instead.
     *
     * @param object the object to initialize
     * @return the initialized version of the object
     */
    public <O extends T> O postProcess(O object);
}

// groovy error Error:(15, 1) Groovyc: Can't have an abstract method in a non-abstract class. The class 'ObjectPostProcessorImpl' must be declared abstract or the method 'java.lang.Object postProcess(java.lang.Object)' must be implemented.
class ObjectPostProcessorImpl implements ObjectPostProcessor<Integer> {

    @Override
    public <O extends Integer> O postProcess(O object) {
        return object
    }
}

class Anon {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ObjectPostProcessor<Integer> objectPostProcessor  = new ObjectPostProcessor<Integer>() {

            /** Groovyc: Can't have an abstract method in a 
             * non-abstract class. 
             * The class 'ObjectPostProcessorImpl' must 
             * be declared abstract or the method 
             * 'java.lang.Object postProcess(java.lang.Object)' 
             * must be implemented. */

            @Override
            public <O extends Integer> O postProcess(O object) {
                return object;
            }
        };

        ObjectPostProcessorImpl objectPostProcessorImplObj = new ObjectPostProcessorImpl();

        System.out.println(objectPostProcessor.postProcess(12));
        System.out.println(objectPostProcessorImplObj.postProcess(12));
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Groovy are you using? Have you tried ignoring all the generics there and just use Object?  Not an answer, but a way out: you could rename that file to .java (and adjust the content) to continue.  Groovyc delegates to javac.  If you want to do "groovy" stuff, you can call it from inside your impl.

Comment: @cfrick, I have tried ignoring all the generics and using just object. This did not work since the compiler expects the return type to be some O which is a subclass of Integer. since Object doesn't meet that criteria we get an error.
Renaming the file to Java worked since this is valid java code. I am trying to understand why it will not work with groovy how ever.

Comment: Are you running this as groovy script inside SoapUI? If yes, then SoapUI comes bundled with it's own JRE. It might explain why the same code works as a java file, and has errors in Groovy. You may try updating the SOAPUI_HOME/bin/soapui.bat to point to your system JRE instead of the bundled one. Hope it's helpful.